# Why does the imageButton not getting accurately placed here?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to place an imageButton (imagebutton4) here like this (in top left): [image]
And here is the XML for this:

```
  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView5"
      android:layout_width="150dp"
      android:layout_height="193dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
      android:text="TextView"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView6"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
  <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/imageButton"
      android:layout_width="50dp"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView5"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView5"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView5"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/play"
      tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView3"
      android:layout_width="134dp"
      android:layout_height="28dp"
      android:text="TextView"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView5"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.511"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView5"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageButton"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.29000002" />
  <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
      android:layout_width="44dp"
      android:layout_height="49dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageButton"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.075"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView5"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView5"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.956"
      tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
```

`imageButton4` is what I want to place in top left.

However, even though I have accurately defined it in AndroidStudio, when it's actually rendered on the device, it's almost protruding out of the larger image view like this. [image]

I tried setting verticalBias but that doesn't help either. I have been struggling with this since past few hours, and I am not sure where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

From all the precise view sizes and very precise biases, it looks like you are over-specifying the layout and not letting it flow naturally. In other words, you have designed a layout for a specific size represented in the designer that can't adapt to other screen sizes.

I don't know what the desired layout is, but I suggest that you start with just the basic view (maybe the *ImageView*) and get it sized and positioned so it looks OK in the designer and on an emulator/actual device. Next you can add the *ImageButton* that looks like it belongs in the center and get it looking good in the designer and emulator. Build up you layout like this and you will find that you are fighting with just one problem at a time instead of the whole layout.

I also suggest that you eliminate exact sizes and precise biases wherever possible and go with `wrap_content` and `0dp` with the appropriate constraints in as many places as you can. Also keep in mind that `match_parent` is discouraged for direct children of a *ConstraintLayout*.